# failure when retrieve data using retrofit android java

Tags: java, android, rest, client, retrofit2

my project is purpose to retrieve data from API that i am create by myself to recyclerview

this is data that i want to retrieve OrderListArray.java :

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name_order")
@Expose
private String name_order;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName_order() {
    return name_order;
}

public void setName_order(String name_order) {
    this.name_order = name_order;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

please help me. the app just show 'failure'. no data

Comment: public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public List<OrderListArray> getOrderlistArray() {
        return orderlistArray;
    }

    public void setOrderlistArray(List<OrderListArray> orderlistArray) {
        this.orderlistArray = orderlistArray;
    }

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Not annotated parameter overrides @EverythingIsNonNull parameter:130

Comment: my code at line 130:          public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<OrderListArray>> call, Response<ArrayList<OrderListArray>> response) {

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.